# in drupal 7 node(content) image remove button not work

Tags: php, drupal-7

i have try to remove image from content(node) in drupal 7 but remove button not work and image not remove.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any error you get ?
check console for js error
check file folder permission.

Comment: no any error coming? and this was you write in comment not as a answer i will down voted for that...